# Does it have a mature algorithm or theory for a scenario about best distribution？

Tags: algorithm

Scenario:
We have 10 kinds of toy,and every kind include 10 toys.
We will distribute toys to 100 children.Every child have different degree of satisfaction for 10 kinds. Tip:In the real project we will have 300000+ children records in my database.

My Question is:How to measure and define the best solution for distribution?
And how to get the result?Please give me a hint.

Some friends suggest me to try KM algorithm, I'm not sure it will work for me.

Thinks.

Comment: Best in the sense of total satisfaction?

Comment: that problem is hard. if you are looking to maximize the sum of satisfactions over all the children you will have to use heuristics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is hard because you haven't decided what you want to optimize, and because many optimization methods will be expensive to run if you have 300K children - or customers - to worry about.

What do you want to optimize? If you try and optimize the sum of some set of per-child satisfaction score, can you really compare the subjective satisfaction of two different children, let alone add them up to produce anything sensible? If you decide on such a system, can you prove that it cannot be distorted by children who decide to lie about their satisfactions, for instance saying that they will be devastated if they don't get one particular toy?

What if somebody decides that the sum of satisfaction scores isn't the right metric, but instead that you should minimize the dis-satisfaction of the most dis-satisfied child?

What if somebody decides that inequality is the real problem, so if there is one very happy child, you should take away their toy and give it to somebody else to minimize the difference in satisfaction between the most and least satisfied child?

What if somebody decides that some children count more than other children, because of something their great-grandparents did, or didn't do?

Just to not be completely negative, here is a cheap scheme, and an attempt to prove a property about it. Put the children in random order and allocate the toys as if each child were to choose according to their preferences in this order - so each child would get the toy they most preferred according to the toys left when they came to choose.

One property you might want for a method of choosing is that, after the toys were distributed, children wouldn't find that they could trade toys amongst themselves to produce a better distribution, making you look silly (aka not a pareto optimal solution). Suppose that such a pattern of trades was possible among the children in this scheme. Consider the trading child who came first among these children in the initial randomization. They chose the toy they wanted most from all those available, so there is in fact nothing the other trading children could offer them that they would prefer. So this scheme is at least not vulnerable to later trades.